# Where's the about box in the Firefox source code?

Tags: firefox

I search in the Mozilla folder using:

```
grep -R "About Mozilla Firefox" ./*
```

but there was no result.

By searching just "about" it prints thousands of lines.

Any idea how to find the about box in the Firefox source code?

Comment: This is a localized string so you won't find it in the source code this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `aboutDialog.*` files, in [source/browser/base/content](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how to find the source code in future, the easiest way is to use [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/dom-inspector-6622/); you can inspect the chrome window and thus find out its URL, then you can search [MXR](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/) for the source file name.